# Programmatically check textboxes for completeness

Tags: c#, textbox

I am looking for a way to figure out if textboxes are filled in in a specific way.

I have the following textboxes:

```
X1 Y1 Z1
X2 Y2 Z2
X3 Y3 Z3
```

Users are expected to input into them continuously. For example, if only X1,Y1 have texts, it's valid. While if X1,Z1 have texts while Y1 hasn't, it's invalid.

The reason for this is because:

```
string G1
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(X1.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Y1.Text))
{
  G1 = "<" + X1.Text + ">";
}
else if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(X1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Y1.Text))
{
  G1 = "<" + X1.Text + ">, ";
}
```

If they skip around then what is printed in the end will not be what is expected.

If you can think of an easier way to do all of this, please share. I am sure that my way of attacking this problem is quite simplistic and inefficient.

Comment: Question not very clear, for example, you only have 9 TextBoxes? Why not put them into array? The code above did not mention what to do with the other TextBoxes except X1, X2.

Comment: I really don't understand your description of the problem. Can you please provide a screenshot of the checkboxes and some further examples of what mean?

Comment: I agree, this question is not clear at all. What do you care what order the user enters text in the boxes? As long as they are filled in before the program actually acts on the values, why would that matter? If you want text entered in a specific order, why offer the user more than one editable item at a time in the first place? Why not just disable or otherwise prevent data entry in an item? Please improve your question by providing a [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing, with a precise explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: I have posted the solution and a better explanation of what the problem was, and why it mattered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found is to use an array of the text boxes, then to iterate over that to determine the text of the filled out boxes. Then add the text from those boxes to a list.

Finally I used joined all of the items of that list, in a way that made the final output correct.

Code I used in the end:

```
string[] cells = new string[] { X1.Text, Y1.Text, Z1.Text, X2.Text, Y2.Text, Z2.Text, X3.Text, Y3.Text, Z3.Text };
List<string> final_cells = new List<string>();
//Process array to determine which cells are full, adds full cells to list
for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
{
  if(cells[i].Length == 0)
  {
   //If cell is empty, continue to the next one
   continue;
  }
  else
  {
   // If cell is full add its contents to the final_cells list
   final_cells.Add(cells[i]);
  }
}
//Join the list to one string
string content = string.Join(">, <", final_cells);
```

Also I am sorry that I did not better explain the original situation.

The purpose of the final application is to output text in a specific format for a minecraft plugin to read. The 3x3 of text boxes is meant to mimic the crafting grid from the game.

The type of recipe this part of the application is supposed to add does not need to use 9 items/blocks, and is not shaped (so it doesn't technically matter where the user inputs each item name). Because of this, the empty boxes have to be completely ignored, and the program needs to know if there is something coming next, so I could not simply say that the recipe ended at the first empty box.

An output of `<item1> <item2>` is not valid, the correct format is `<item1>, <item2>`. However the input can also be a single item... so this `<only_item>` is a valid format.

I hope it is clear both what the function of this is, but also why this was important for my application.